# Microsoft MVC 4 Parameter as XML in POST body

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, html-post

I am new to microsoft's MVC so please forgive my newbie question.  We are porting a Ruby/Rails application to MS MVC 4.  We will be doing this over time so the .NET MVC must be able to consume Ruby/Rails api request without modification.  I am having trouble deserializing the xml in the POST body to an object.  When I place a break point on the return line the value of login is null.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The API request is authenticate...here is the request from the client.

```
POST http://cloudcare.webservices.local/users/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: cloudcare.webservices.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 132
Accept: text/xml

<authenticate> 
<login>david</login>
<password>secure</password>
<user_type_id>2</user_type_id>
</authenticate>
```

Here is the Api Controller

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private IUserRepository repository;

    public UsersController(IUserRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public AuthenticateUserViewModel authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateUserViewModel login)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the parameter class

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "authenticate")]
public class AuthenticateUserViewModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "login")]
    public string Login { set; get; }

    [DataMember(Name = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "user_type_id")]
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );

        var unity = new UnityContainer();
        unity.RegisterType<Controllers.UsersController>();
        unity.RegisterType<Repository.IUserRepository, Repository.Repositories.UserRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    }
}
```

Comment: For starter: you can try to set the Content-Type in your request to `text/xml` and also removing the `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;` because as far as I know the XmlSerializer does not understand the `DataMember` attributes so it will have problems with the different casing Login  vs login

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I have tried the content-type change and did not work.  Also, I did try the uppercase login and it did not work either.

Comment: I changed the dataContract and dataMember attributes to XmlRoot and XmlElement attributes and that worked.  Thanks for the tip.